# how to remove billing information in authorize.net sending xml request?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

how to remove billing or shipping information while sending request to authorize.net cim api. i have tried like this but not getting any response
below is the xml format

```
$input_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<getHostedProfilePageRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
<merchantAuthentication>
<name>xxxxxxx</name>
<transactionKey>xxxxxxxxx</transactionKey>
</merchantAuthentication>
<hostedProfileSettings>
<setting>
<settingName>hostedProfileReturnUrl</settingName>
<settingValue>https://www.google.co.in/</settingValue>
</setting>
<setting>
<settingName>hostedProfileReturnUrlText</settingName>
<settingValue>Continue to xtg.</settingValue>
</setting>
<setting>
<settingName>hostedProfilePageBorderVisible</settingName>
<settingValue>true</settingValue>
</setting>
</hostedProfileSettings>
</getHostedProfilePageRequest>';

    //setting the curl parameters.
$url = "https://test.authorize.net/profile/addPayment";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "xmlRequest=" . $input_xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //convert the XML result into array
    $array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);
    print_r('<pre>');
    print_r($array_data);
    print_r('</pre>');
```

Comment: What are you expecting the output of `$array_data` to be, and what is it actually? Otherwise we don't know what you need and how we can help.

Comment: actually i am sending the xml request to authorize.net and getting response form it. but i am not getting any error or any data from the url request

Comment: What do you need your outcome to be. Which part of your code needs to do something that it currently does not do, or what value should a variable be at a specific point?

Comment: suggest you consider using the authorize php sdk, it has specific examples for CIM https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes now it is working. I gave the correct api login id